# How to add title (like group header) in the telerik's radlistbox

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, telerik, radlistbox

Code:

```
<telerik:RadListBox x:Name="testStates">

</telerik:RadListBox>
```

I searched and not found a proper way to add a header / title in the radlistbox.

How to add title / header (*like group header in asp.net ajax telerik control radlistbox*) in the **telerik's radlistbox in wpf** ?

Can we achieve the solution by any other way if we can't able to do it in a recommended way?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer relates to the AJAX and not WPF controls, however have left code here for reference purposes and/or until a suitable WPF solution is found**

According to the Telerik Forum:

> RadListBox does not support such Group (Header) Items out-of-the-box.

The only way you could achieve something similar to the headers is by using an [`ItemTemplate`](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/listbox/examples/functionality/templates/defaultcs.aspx) and using the (undocumented) `SelectedIndexChanging` including the code to cancel the event should the user attempt to select it *(the following code has not been syntax or error checked and should probably only be used as a guideline)*

```
function jsEventHandler(sender,eventArgs) {
    var selectedItem = eventArgs.get_item(); // gets the selected item
    if(/*Insert code for determining whether the item is a "header item"*/){
        eventArgs.set_cancel(true);
    }
}
```

You'll find your answer in this [Telerik Forum Post](http://www.telerik.com/forums/title-in-listbox)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, I am searching the solution for `WPF` and your solution is related with `Asp.Net Ajax`. If possible, please provide me the solution related with `WPF`. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I completely missed the wpf part (I'll wear my glasses next time!) Looking at the forums it looks unlikely that it is currently supported with the wpf controls: http://www.telerik.com/forums/can-a-listbox-have-headers